# Smarter Method for Parseing XML from Amazon API for Browser Nodes

Tags: php

Wondering if anyone knows a better method that can teach me a smart way to handle this so i wont run into undefined warning when the xml comes back smaller

```
   // Category
$main = $response->Items->Item->BrowseNodes->BrowseNode;
$cat1 = $main->Name;
$cat2 = $main->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name;
$cat3 = $main->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name;
$cat4 = $main->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name;
//$cat5 = $main->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name;
//$cat6 = $main->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name;
//$cat7 = $main->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name;
//$cat8 = $main->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name;
//$cat9 = $main->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name;

switch ('Styles')
{
    case $cat1;
        $SubCategory = 'not found';
        break;
    case $cat2;
        $SubCategory = $cat1;   
        break;
    case $cat3;
        $SubCategory = $cat2;
        break;
    case $cat4;
        $SubCategory = $cat3;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop in combination with a variable which holds the current node:

```
$curNode = $response->Items->Item->BrowseNodes->BrowseNode;

while ($curNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode) {
  $curNode = $curNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode;
}

$subCategory = $curNode->Name;
```

You can also use a recursive function:

```
function getSubCategory($rootNode) {
  if ($rootNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode) {
    return getSubCategory($rootNode);
  }
  else {
    return $rootNode->Name;
  }
}
getSubCategory($response->Items->Item->BrowseNodes->BrowseNode);
```

Note that `$var->Ancestors->BrowseNode` checks for the existence of those keys in my pseudo code. You may need to replace it by `($var->Ancestors && $var->Ancestors->BrowseNode)` in your real code.